# How to Parse Java-script contains[dynamic] on web-page[html] using Python?

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I am building a spider and I am using Beautiful soup to parse the contain of particular URL. 
Now, some sites are using Java-script to show dynamic contain which will be shown to user once some action [clicking or time] happens. 
Beautiful soup just parse the static contain which is before the java-script tag has run. 
I want the contain after java-script run. 
Is there any way to do this?

I can think of one way: Grab the url, open the browser and run this URL and java-script tags as well. And then pass this url to Beautiful soup, which can see contains which java-script[dynamic contains] has produced. However, if I am crawling millions of links then this solution is not useful. If there is some in-built module available which can generate dynamic contain of the Html page before hand.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for accurately parsing Javascript-enhanced content from web pages is to load the page via a browser engine. Luckily there are ways to automate this in Python.

The method I've had the most success with is to use the [pywebkitgtk project](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/) which lets you programmatically create and control instances of the Webkit browser engine from within a Python application.  I also use the [jswebkit module](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-jswebkit) to simplify execution of Javascript in the page context.

Another option is [PyQt4's QtWebKit class](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtwebkit.html) which I've only used for experimentation.

Here is a working example of using pywebkitgtk and jswebkit together to extract data from a Webkit-rendered page.  In a production environment you'll want to run several of these processors in parallel, each rendering to its own instance of the [X virtual framebuffer (Xvfb)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).

```
import os

import gtk
import jswebkit
import lxml.html
import pygtk
import webkit

def load_finished(view, frame):
    # called when the document finishes loading
    if frame != view.get_main_frame():
        return
    ctx = jswebkit.JSContext(frame.get_global_context())
    res = ctx.EvaluateScript('window.location.href')
    print res
    res = ctx.EvaluateScript('document.body.innerHTML')
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(res)
    print tree.xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')

# initialization
pygtk.require20()
gtk.gdk.threads_init()

# create the webview and hook up callbacks to signals
view = webkit.WebView()
view.set_size_request(1024, 768)
view.connect('load-finished', load_finished)

# configure the webview
props = view.get_settings()
props.set_property('enable-java-applet', False)
props.set_property('enable-plugins', False)
props.set_property('enable-page-cache', False)

# create a window to host the webview
win = gtk.Window()
win.add(view)
win.show_all()

# open google front page
view.open('http://www.google.com')

# spin, processing gtk events
while True:
    try:
        while gtk.events_pending():
            gtk.main_iteration(False)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Example output:

```
http://www.google.com/
[<InputElement 2a64a78 name='btnG' type='submit'>, <InputElement 2a64bb0 name='btnG' type='submit'>, <InputElement 2a64ae0 name='btnI' type='submit'>]
```

Comment: Thanks samplebias. Thing is, it gives me an error saying " could not open display"... I have tried everything like set display variable or use -c option with python. However, the same error I am getting. Is there any way?

Comment: The problem stems from gtk/webkit being unable to connect to your X display to show the browser window. If you are ssh-ing into a server, you need to be using X and enable X11 forwarding on your session, e.g. `ssh -Y [remote host]`. This should set the shell $DISPLAY variable, which you can verify with `echo $DISPLAY`

Comment: Sure, here's a link to the [jswebkit homepage](http://packages.debian.org/source/sid/python-jswebkit) and a direct link to [download the jswebkit 0.0.3 source code](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python-jswebkit/python-jswebkit_0.0.3.orig.tar.gz). I've only used this code on Ubuntu 10.04+; I have no experience running under Centos 5.x.

Comment: Thanks man. I am working on that, I will let you know once I get it done. I am just curious about the package[jswebkit]. It has .pyx file and .pyi files. For now, I am planning to put these all files in site-packages. Question is, do I need to install anything related to CPython?

Comment: I may not be able to help with build info in detail, as I've personally never built the Webkit/JavascriptCore stack on Centos. I'm pretty sure jswebkit will require a recent version of Cython (like 0.14) to build. Once you have Cython installed you should be able to build an RPM for jswebkit with `python setup.py bdist_rpm`.