# Programmatically download text that doesn't appear in the page source

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm writing a crawler in Python.
Given a single web page, I extract it's `Html` content in the following manner:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')
html = response.read()
```

But some text components **don't** appear in the Html page source, for example in [this page](http://jebbushemails.com/email/results/19990106/1) (redirected to the index, please access one of the dates and view a specific mail) if you view page source you will see that the mail text doesn't appear in the source but seems to be loaded by JS.

How can I programmatically download this text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option here would be to make a POST request to the URL responsible for the email search and parse the JSON results (mentioning @recursive since he suggested the idea first). Example using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package:

```
import requests

data = {
    'year': '1999',
    'month': '05',
    'day': '20',
    'locale': 'en-us'
}
response = requests.post('http://jebbushemails.com/api/email.py', data=data)

results = response.json()
for email in results['emails']:
    print email['dateCentral'], email['subject']
```

Prints:

```
1999-05-20T00:48:23-05:00 Re: FW: The Reason Study of Rail Transportation in Hillsborough
1999-05-20T04:07:26-05:00 Escambia County School Board
1999-05-20T06:29:23-05:00 RE: Escambia County School Board
...
1999-05-20T22:56:16-05:00 RE: School Board
1999-05-20T22:56:19-05:00 RE: Emergency Supplemental just passed 64-36
1999-05-20T22:59:32-05:00 RE:
1999-05-20T22:59:33-05:00 RE: (no subject)
```

---

A different approach here would be to let a real browser handle the dynamic javascript part of the page load with the help of [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) browser automation framework:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # can also be, for example, webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://jebbushemails.com/email/search')

# click 1999-2000
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(., "1999 – 2000")]')
button.click()

# click 20
cell = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@role="grid"]//span[. = "20"]')
cell.click()

# click Submit
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[span[1]/text() = "Submit"]')
submit.click()

# wait for result to appear
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@analytics-event]")))

# get the results
for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@analytics-event]'):
    date, subject = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    print date.text, subject.text
```

Prints:

```
6:24:27am Fw: Support Coordination
6:26:18am Last nights meeting
6:52:16am RE: Support Coordination
7:09:54am St. Pete Times article
8:05:35am semis on the interstate
...
6:07:25pm Re: Appointment
6:18:07pm Re: Mayor Hood
8:13:05pm Re: Support Coordination
```

Note that a browser here can also be *headless*, like [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/). And, if there is no display for browser to work in - you can fire up a *virtual one*, see examples here:

- [How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)
- [Headless browser testing with download functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942322/headless-browser-testing-with-download-functionality)

Comment: good answer.  I'd add something about headless frameworks like phantomjs or casper.js also

Answer (score 2):

You can make a request to the actual ajax service, instead of trying to use the web interface.

For example, a post request to http://jebbushemails.com/api/email.py with this form data will yield 80kb of easily parse-able json.

```
year:1999
month:05
day:20
locale:en-us
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python expert but any function such as urlopen only gets you the static HTML, not executing it. What you need is a browser engine of some kind to actually parse and execute the JavaScript.
It seems to be answered here:

[How to Parse Java-script contains[dynamic] on web-page[html] using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738024/how-to-parse-java-script-containsdynamic-on-web-pagehtml-using-python)