# When new objects are loaded, it does not appear in the source page by django-endless-pagination

Tags: jquery, html, django, dom, django-endless-pagination

Suppose a new page is loaded, with one entry (i.e. `snapgroup`). And I can view the source page which includes that one loaded entry in the html. So when I scroll down, it loads another entry. Now when I view the source page nothing has been changed, and the newly loaded entry is not included in the html, only the first entry exist instead of two entries.

However it does display in the browser. And since I am using a lightbox, when I open an image of second entry from the slider it does open the image but if I click next, it starts displaying the images only from the first entry. What's going on?

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596309/programmatically-download-text-that-doesnt-appear-in-the-page-source). But both our questions are different.

```
def snaps(request,template = 'snaps.html',
                  page_template = 'snapgroups.html' ):

    context = {}    
    snapgroup = SnapGroup.objects.order_by('-date')

    context.update( {'snapgroup': snapgroup, 'page_template': page_template,} )

    # override the template and use the 'page' style instead.
    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template

    return render_to_response(
        template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

snaps.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main_content %}
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="snap_wrapper" class="container">
        <hr>
        {% if snapgroup.count > 0 %}

            <div class="endless_page_template">
                {% include page_template %}
            </div>

            {% block js %}
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
                <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless_on_scroll.js"></script>
                <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $.endlessPaginate({paginateOnScroll: true,
                    endless_on_scroll_margin : 10
                    });
                </script>
            {% endblock %}           

        {% else %}
            <li><p>No SNAPGROUP yet!</p></li>
            <span class="clear_both"></span>
        {% endif %}

    {% load disqus_tags %}
    {% disqus_show_comments %}

    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

snapgroups.html:

```
{% load endless %}

{% paginate 1 snapgroup %}

{% for sg in snapgroup %}
    <h4 id="combination" class="snap_date">{{sg.date|date:'l'}}, {{sg.date}}</h4>
    <ul>
    {% for snap in sg.snap_set.all %}
        <li><a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{snap.image}}" data-imagelightbox="f"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{snap.image}}" alt="{{snap.caption}}" /></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
        <span class="clear_both"></span>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}

{% show_more "more..." "working" %}
```

Comment: endless-pagination adds entries by Javascript, they wouldn't show up in view source. You can use the browser dev tools to see the HTML.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is there anyway that I can use it in my lightbox.